# Git Rebase - Rebase Shared Remote Onto Local, Avoid Merge Commit?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding (overcoming?) the fear in Git Rebase as it pertains to a shared branch but with local commits that haven't been pushed yet.

Let's say I have a local branch `my-feature` which is 2 commits ahead of the tracked remote `origin/my-feature`. This branch is also shared and worked on by other developers.

I am pretty certain that if I pull, I'll have conflicts, and will probably end up with a really nasty merge commit, which I'd like to avoid. My thought was that if I can rebase the remote on top of my local branch (and rewrite the commit history only for my 2 new commits) that I can fix the merge conflicts locally and avoid the nasty merge commit. But, I'm not sure if that's how rebase works in this situation.

The general advice seems to be "avoid rebasing shared branches", but could someone enlighten me on how this would play out in my scenario? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rebase the remote onto your local branch - that would modify the history of the remote branch (and would require a local branch to track that rebase anyways). Instead, rebase your local `my-feature` onto `origin/my-feature`:

```
git checkout my-feature

# git add and git commit lots of stuff

git fetch origin
git rebase origin/my-feature
```

Any commits you have added onto `my-feature` since the last time you fetched `origin/my-feature` will be applied on top of the latest top of `origin/my-feature`. That way, you are not rewriting history of `origin/my-feature`. That is, from the point of view of other users, you are only adding commits to it.

Just a general tip I give to a lot of people - erase `pull` from your dictionary. Just forget that concept even exists. Do `fetch` first, then look at all the branches using `gitk --all` or equivalent, and decide how you want to progress (merge, rebase, whatever).

Comment: Makes total sense. That's sort of what I was saying, but I think my terminology was a bit off. I was saying to rebase the remote on top of my branch, but I really meant the opposite. I tried exactly what you said and it seemed to work perfectly. Thanks so much, it's just what I needed!